# python join followed by split does not return the original list

Tags: python, string

Very simply put:

```
'_'.join(['ACT_X','IEC']).split('_')
# ['ACT', 'X', 'IEC']
```

From 2 strings that I joined, by the supposedly reverse operation I get 3 strings.

I can see why this is happening, and I get that perhaps the point of `join` and `split` is not to handle text that contains the separator itself.
However, in other `python` code this is correctly handled, e.g. if I write out a csv, and some text contains commas, it is quoted, so the correct columns are read back in.

Can you think of a way to do this (join a list of strings by a separator) so that if any of the joined strings contains the separator, the joined result is fully reversible to the original strings?

In fact I was surprised by the above, because I thought the very point of `join` was to do something different and more sophisticated than a simple `+` between strings (that is the case in other programming languages).
Now I am wondering what the difference actually is...

Comment: Which other programming languages have `join` operators that do something more complicated than chained string concatenation? (I'm genuinely curious, can't think of any)

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Is there any structure to your data?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : Biovia PilotScript, array function 'Contract'. The result of the above is "ACT_X"_IEC

Comment: @wkl : I have separate columns in a data frame, and I need to create a new column with the concatenation of those separate columns. The concatenation will then be used for saving and handling data in a more compact format and for grouping. Thus I would prefer to do it in a way that preserves the information of where the parts came from. Also, you can imagine a data integrity issue: ["ACT_X", "IEC"] would give you exactly the same output as ["ACT", "X_IEC"], which, I hope we agree, is not really good practice.

Comment: In fact from my answer to Mathias, I am thinking now that a solution could be to quote any of the input strings that contain the separator, so essentially writing my own join function. Doable, but I am surprised that it does not exist OOB. As for the split, that would be more challenging, I imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use built-in `csv` module:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

lst = ["ACT_X", "IEC"]

s = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(s, delimiter="_")
writer.writerow(lst)
s.seek(0)

row = s.read()
print(row)
```

Prints:

```
"ACT_X"_IEC
```

---

To read it back to list:

```py
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(row), delimiter="_")
print(next(reader))
```

Prints:

```py
['ACT_X', 'IEC']
```

Answer (score 1):

Joining them with a character that never appears in the strings is the easiest way out. Depending on your data, suitable characters for this purpose might include `"\n"`, `"\t"` or `"\xf1"`.